# Run odoo as service

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I have installed odoo 10 on ubuntu 16.04. Now i need to create a service for odoo. I have tried below steps, but getting an error:

```
Starting odoo-server: start-stop-daemon: --start needs --exec or --startas
Try 'start-stop-daemon --help' for more information.
/etc/init.d/odoo-server: 39: /etc/init.d/odoo-server: --chuid: not found
odoo-server.
```

odoo-server

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: odoo-server
# Required-Start: $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop: $remote_fs $syslog
# Should-Start: $network
# Should-Stop: $network
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: Odoo ERP
# Description: Odoo is a complete ERP business solution.
### END INIT INFO
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin
# Change the Odoo source files location according your needs.
DAEMON=/opt/odoo/odoo-10.0/odoo-bin
# Use the name convention of your choice
NAME=odoo-server
DESC=odoo-server
# Specify the user name (Default: odoo).
USER=odoo
# Specify an alternate config file (Default: /etc/odoo-server.conf).
CONFIGFILE="/etc/odoo.conf"
# pidfile
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
# Additional options that are passed to the Daemon.

DAEMON_OPTS="-c $CONFIGFILE"
[ -x $DAEMON ] || exit 0
[ -f $CONFIGFILE ] || exit 0
checkpid() {
[ -f $PIDFILE ] || return 1
pid=`cat $PIDFILE`
[ -d /proc/$pid ] && return 0
return 1
}
case "${1}" in
  start)
echo -n "Starting ${DESC}: "
start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile ${PIDFILE}
--chuid ${USER} --background --make-pidfile \
--exec ${DAEMON} -- ${DAEMON_OPTS}
echo "${NAME}."
;;
stop)
echo -n "Stopping ${DESC}: "
start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile ${PIDFILE} \
--oknodo
echo "${NAME}."
;;
restart|force-reload)
echo -n "Restarting ${DESC}: "
start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile ${PIDFILE} \
--oknodo
sleep 1
start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile ${PIDFILE}
--chuid ${USER} --background --make-pidfile \
--exec ${DAEMON} -- ${DAEMON_OPTS}
echo "${NAME}."
;;
*)
N=/etc/init.d/${NAME}
echo "Usage: ${NAME} {start|stop|restart|force-reload}"
exit 1
;;
esac
exit 0
```

i executed this command:

```
chmod 755 /etc/init.d/odoo-server

chown ubuntu: /etc/init.d/openerp-server
```

user is: `odoo`.

config file: `/etc/odoo.conf`

Odoo runnig like this way:

`sudo su - odoo -s /bin/bash`
  `~/odoo-10.0/odoo-bin` .

But i can't start as service.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are missing one thing inside your file.

Please have a look your missing part and paste init script is as like below in your file.

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: odoo-server
# Required-Start: $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop: $remote_fs $syslog
# Should-Start: $network
# Should-Stop: $network
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: Odoo ERP
# Description: Odoo is a complete ERP business solution.
### END INIT INFO
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin
# Change the Odoo source files location according your needs.
DAEMON=/opt/odoo/odoo-10.0/odoo-bin
# Use the name convention of your choice
NAME=odoo-server
DESC=odoo-server
# Specify the user name (Default: odoo).
USER=odoo
# Specify an alternate config file (Default: /etc/odoo-server.conf).
CONFIGFILE="/etc/odoo.conf"
# pidfile
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
# Additional options that are passed to the Daemon.

DAEMON_OPTS="-c $CONFIGFILE"
[ -x $DAEMON ] || exit 0
[ -f $CONFIGFILE ] || exit 0
checkpid() {
[ -f $PIDFILE ] || return 1
pid=`cat $PIDFILE`
[ -d /proc/$pid ] && return 0
return 1
}
case "${1}" in
  start)
echo -n "Starting ${DESC}: "
start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile ${PIDFILE} \
--chuid ${USER} --background --make-pidfile \
--exec ${DAEMON} -- ${DAEMON_OPTS}
echo "${NAME}."
;;
stop)
echo -n "Stopping ${DESC}: "
start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile ${PIDFILE} \
--oknodo
echo "${NAME}."
;;
restart|force-reload)
echo -n "Restarting ${DESC}: "
start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile ${PIDFILE} \
--oknodo
sleep 1
start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile ${PIDFILE} \
--chuid ${USER} --background --make-pidfile \
--exec ${DAEMON} -- ${DAEMON_OPTS}
echo "${NAME}."
;;
*)
N=/etc/init.d/${NAME}
echo "Usage: ${NAME} {start|stop|restart|force-reload}"
exit 1
;;

esac
exit 0
```

I think you are missing some important part `\` which is for unix command when one command is in more then one line.

Inside two lines you are missing `\` after `${PIDFILE}`, Those lines are as below.

```
1) "Inside Start case" : 
start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile ${PIDFILE}
--chuid ${USER} --background --make-pidfile \
--exec ${DAEMON} -- ${DAEMON_OPTS}

2) "Inside Restart Case" :
start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile ${PIDFILE}
--chuid ${USER} --background --make-pidfile \
--exec ${DAEMON} -- ${DAEMON_OPTS}
```

Thats why you are getting below error that :

```
Starting odoo-server: start-stop-daemon: --start needs --exec or --startas
Try 'start-stop-daemon --help' for more information.
/etc/init.d/odoo-server: 39: /etc/init.d/odoo-server: --chuid: not found
odoo-server.
```

I hope you are getting the things and can run your Odoo using service successfully.